# uri are impossible to work with?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, vb.net, uri

My goal is to setup an ICC color transforms acessible to visitors of my ASP.net web site using Windows Imaging Component.

I first experimented with WIC inside a friendly WinForm C# using VS2013 -- my gratitude to those, here, btw, who have shared their WIC code.

In this C# application, I use the following Uri declations without a hitch :

```
BitmapSource bSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\tmp\Flowers.jpg"));
```

But all hell breaks loose when I try to use the same code in my ASP.net VB.net code behind?

On my web site, my images are stored in a directory called "Images" and my ICC profiles reside in a directory called "Profiles".

This is how I initially codes the Uri declaratinon to my BitmapSource :

```
Dim myBitmapSource As New BitmapImage(New Uri("~/Images/RGB.png"))
```

And this is how I coded the Uri to my ColorContext declaration :

```
Dim sourceColorContext As New ColorContext(New Uri("("~/Profiles/CIERGB.icc"))
```

I thought this would be cinch.

The compiler gladly accepted this code as syntactically correct but when I ran the site with F5, I was greeted with errors? The first is "Invalid URI format exception" which refers to my RGB image "path" declaration.

I spent a fair part of the day searching this error, here and elsewhere, and I resolved to change the Uri declation thusly :

```
New Uri("http//www.mysite.foo/Images/RGB.png"))
```

This seemed to make the runtime happy, but I suspect that I'm not out of the woods yet?

The second error is giving me much grief. The error I am getting is "file not found". Seems the runtime can't find CIERGB.icc on my website even though I can see it physically with my FTP client. So I thought I would apply the same fix to the path of my ICC profile as as I did above and got :

```
Dim sourceColorContext As New ColorContext(New Uri("http//www.mysite.foo/Profiles/CIERGB.icc"))
```

But that is still deem not acceptable for the runtime, my ICC profile still can't be found?

I will continue searching the issue on my own, in case, but I never expected I would run in so much hardship for what looks like "straightforward" path declarations...

Comment: In your last url, is `Profils` a typo ?

Comment: Doesn't mather if you can access it through the FTP, can you access it through the browser? I don't think you need to use URI if you are specifing a path. Just pass the string of the path.

Comment: Sorry, yes, indeed, it is a typo. It should be "Profiles".

Comment: This works very well http://www.graxx.ca/images/nemoRGB-crop.png

Comment: This works very well too:http://www.graxx.ca/profils/photodiscRGBi.zip

Comment: But not this http://www.graxx.ca/profils/photodiscRGBi.icc?
It seems that, if the file is not an "image" or a "zip" file, it simply isn't visible off the server, even though it is there physically. Could be some security issue?

Comment: If you can't access the file with the browser this mean that your web server is blocking the file. Some server only allows specific file type to be downloaded to prevent people from downloading for example config files and databases.

Comment: And the other problem is that `~/...` is just not valid URI syntax in .NET. So the source of both problems is not the Uri class.

Comment: I found the fix for my Uri problem. But now, I am running into System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' HRESULT : 0x80070000.
That's it. I am finished.

Comment: Anyone ever heard about a "downloadable Hresult 0×80070000 Repair Kit" to fix Hresult 0×80070000 error as seen on  http://winwiki.org/hresult-0x80070000/? Naturally, no such kit are to be found on Microsoft site or elsewhere on the internet. I was reading elsewhere on this site that this is a bug and was not a big priority at Microsoft :(

Comment: Oh! BTW, my ASP host fix the mysterious invisible ICC profile bug. Now it works. Makes sense that they configure their server for the minimum types of files visible by default.

Comment: Very frustrating that my code worked flawlessly on my Windows 8 machine but throws an exception when ran from ASP... I thought I was homefree.